# Is there a webdesign guideline to add dates to web pages?

Tags: website-design, guidelines, dates

It seems like whenever I visit a website whether it's a tutorial, or article, etc, they rarely write the date, which makes you wonder if it's 1 year old or 10 year old, especially if it's software related that could become obsolete very fast.

I don't know if there is a webdesign guideline for this? If so, then why isn't the vast majority following it?

Comment: What do you mean with "webdesign guideline"?

Comment: Like best practices of some sort. You know like I remember reading some about not using text colors on a background that's hard to read. I don't know if these are official or unofficial rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that it's rare you don't see a date, but yes, the rule of thumb for publishing most any content is to provide date information along with it. This is how most publishing has always been (books, papers, magazines, etc.) and that isn't really any different on the web.

It obviously matters more for certain content than other.

I wouldn't say the vast majority of web sites ignore this. Many do, but certainly many do not and publish dates as you would expect. I can't say why some sites don't put a date on their content.